# JRebel and Oracle ADF, JDeveloper

Tags: java, oracle, jrebel, hotdeploy

Do any of you have any experience with JRebel (Hot deploy)? And if so, have you any experience with JRebel + Oracle ADF (JDeveloper)?

We are thinking about buying some licenses, but have only tried it for 14 days (free period)

Are there any other alternatives? Does anyone have bad experience with JRebel, or the Zeroturnaround team?

Comment: Probably best to move this to http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

JRebel ADF integration allows ADF page definition files to be reloaded and it also patches ADF implementation of JSF lifecycle allowing Mojarra plugin to do the rest.

If you evaluated JRebel for 14 days already, did it work for you or does it require more integration for your particular use cases? Just file the feature request / bug report if something is causing troubles.

There is also the the [JRebel plugin for JDeveloper](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ide/jdeveloper.html) what is aimed to simplify the setup